# Gracenote RhythmAPI request using POST method

Tags: java, http-post, gracenote

I am working with Spring MVC and I use simple HTML form. I am sending HTTPS request to gracenote using GET method but I need to do it using POST method. With GET it works fine but I can not get it to work with POST method. And I need to recieve JSON response not XML. Is it even possible to do it with POST method and recieve JSON response ? I know that by constructing XML request link I send via POST method but then I recieve XML response ( info: https://github.com/richadams/java-gracenote ).

Code for GET method:

My HTML form in recommended.jsp

```
<spring:url value="/recommendedSongs.view" var="formUrl"/>
<form:form action="${formUrl}" method="POST" modelAttribute="command">
    <form:label path="artistName">Artist name</form:label>
    <form:input path="artistName" id="artistInput"/>
    <form:label path="trackTitle">Track title</form:label>
    <form:input path="trackTitle" id="trackInput"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form:form>
```

Model getters and setters

```
public class RecommendedFormDataCommand {

    private String artistName;
    private String trackTitle;

    public String getArtistName() {
        return artistName;
    }

    public void setArtistName(String artistName) {
        this.artistName = artistName;
    }

    public String getTrackTitle() {
        return trackTitle;
    }

    public void setTrackTitle(String trackTitle) {
        this.trackTitle = trackTitle;
    }

}
```

Controller code to recieve data from HTML form

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/recommended.view")
public ModelAndView artistTrackForm() {
    return new ModelAndView("recommended", "command", new RecommendedFormDataCommand());
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/recommendedSongs.view")
public String artistTrackFormData(@ModelAttribute("command") RecommendedFormDataCommand rfd,
                                  ModelMap model) throws IOException {
```

HTTPS GET request

```
https://{CLIENT ID}.web.cddbp.net/webapi/json/1.0/radio/recommend?client={CLIENT ID}-{CLIENT TAG}&user={CLIENT ID}&seed=(text_artist_kendrick+lamar;text_track_King+Kunta%2Cking+kunta)&return_count=25
```

NOTE: I do not want to show my client tag and id so I replaced them with these: {CLIENT ID} and {CLIENT TAG}

It would be really helpful if someone could tell me if it is possible to send HTTPS request via POST method and recieve JSON response aand give simple example.

Comment: A little example of what you've tried would be nice. And why all those tags? Please remove irrelevant tags.

Comment: Sorry for that, I did not notice that I put asp.net tag

Answer (score 0):

> if it is possible to send HTTPS request via POST method and recieve
>   JSON response

I believe this is not possible.
As you already know you can do what you want with GET and have no reason to use POST. The CLIENT ID TAG in the HTTPS URL will be encrypted if this is what you are worrying about.

UPDATED: I looked into it a bit more and believe this is possible but the payload you send with your POST request should be XML and not JSON. You can get your response back in JSON using the following;

POST https://c.web.cddbp.net/webapi/FORMAT/1.0/radio/
(replace FORMAT with 'json' or 'xml')

Comment: well I would need to use POST when I need to handle a lot of information as GET is good only for small amount of data. For example, with GET it would be inefficient to work with images while POST has no problem with images